# flutter icon is not centered in container

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-container

I was trying to center the icon in a circular background but it failed even if I use a center widget as child unless increase container size.

```
    Container(
                  height: 22,
                  width: 22,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Color(0xffF7825C),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
             Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 22,
              width: 22,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Color(0xffF7825C),
              ),
              child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 22 
                ),
            )
```

Comment: it worked for ,e while placing a size to the icon .

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the size of your icon with `size` attribute, so your Icon widget should look like this

```
Icon(
    Icons.add,
    color: Colors.white,
    size: 22
)
```

Comment: at last I solved it by changing it to a CircleAvatar widget so it align center with out any hassle,

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `RawMaterialButton`, You can set it like this

```
RawMaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              fillColor: Color(0xffF7825C),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                size: 22.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              shape: CircleBorder(),
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue can be solve by giving size to Icon

```
Container(
    width: 40,
    height: 20,                  
    child: Icon(
        Icons.arrow_right_alt_outlined,
        color: Colors.white,
        size: 20,),
    ),
```

the above thing works because now we have the container which can contain whole icons size
( 40x20(container) can contain 20(icon))
but if this icons size gets bigger than container dimension there we meshed up the centering of icon inside container

hope this explanation works!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code :-

```
Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height: 22,
                  width: 22,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Color(0xffF7825C),
                  ),
                  child: Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 22 
                    ),
                )
```

Answer (score -2):

use the following :

```
Container(
              height: 22,
              width: 22,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Color(0xffF7825C),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              
            )
```